# Pass value from Django to Ajax, how to identify variable type?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

In Django, I have a variable `flag=True`.
I pass it to script in Html :

```
<script>
    if({{flag}}==True) do something
</script>
```

I assume `do something` will be called, but it is not. It looks like True not equal to True. Could anyone teach me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like this

```
<script>
    {% if flag %}
     do something
    {% endif %}
</script>
```

You are trying to check the javascript condition with python boolean value. The above example is in django template engine. But still you want to check the condition in javascript, you have to do like this.

```
<script>
    if ({{flag}}) {
       do something
    }
</script>
```